# Testing Conditionally Initialized RestController based on active profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have the following class, which is loaded conditionally based on the profile. I want it to only load for assisting in lower environments and not production:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@Profile("!prod")
public class FooController {

    private Bar bar;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createFoo(){
        bar.something();
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

I would like to have the following tests for this class:

```
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("prod")
public class FooControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private Bar bar;

    @InjectMocks
    private FooController subjectUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(subjectUnderTest)
                .build();
    }

@Test
public void givenProdProfile_whenCreateFoo_thenNotFoundResponseReturned() throws Exception {
        doNothing().when(mockBar).something();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/foo"))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
```

and then another test class to test this case, with @ActiveProfile('non-prod'):

- givenNonProdProfile_whenCreateFoo_thenAcceptedResponseReturned

I am confused on how to properly test this. I've tried many different different approaches, and none of them seem to properly test the class. I've tried annotating my test class with @ActiveProfile, etc.

I suppose the crux of my question, is how can I test different profiles with MockMvc and Mockito?

Comment: Define "none of them seem to properly test the class". If your test class has `@SpringBootTest` (or sliced test annotation for web mvc), then it'll create a context based on whatever classes/`@Component`/`@Configuration` are within it's reach. You use whatever is in the context to test. That is all there is when it comes to "testing properly".

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles("test")` simply says: the test class this annotation is applied on will use "test" profile for creating the application context.